# AJAX XML data to $scope, synchronicity issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Because I have some many controllers doing more or less the same thing, I want to create a function that takes the filename of the XML file and assigns it to a `$scope` variable.  The obvious problem is the asynchronous call.

Is there a "pause" or something that would prevent the `ngXMLFile` function from ending until the AJAX call is complete so that it's not assigning `undefined`to the `$scope.authors` because `data` in `sectionController` is `undefined`?

I tried this `$.when` but it's clear I'm not using it correctly.

```
function ngXMLFile($http, filename) {
    $http({method: "GET", url: "/xml/"+filename+".xml"}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return $.xml2json(data);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
}

function sectionController($scope, $http) {
    $.when(ngXMLFile($http, "authors")).then(function(data) {
        $scope.authors = data;
    });
}
```

XML File (authors.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<authors>
    <author>
        <name>
            <first>Bob</first>
            <last>Smith</last>
        </name>
    </author>
    <author>
        <name>
            <first>Joe</first>
            <last>King</last>
        </name>
    </author>
</authors>
```

Comment: `ngXMLFile` has to return a promise. Right now it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is pass the callback function to your Ajax call function, for instance:

```
function ngXMLFile($http, filename, callback) {
    $http({method: "GET", url: "/xml/"+filename+".xml"}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
                 callback($.xml2json(data));
            }
        ).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
            }
        );
}

function sectionController($scope, $http) {
    ngXMLFile($http, "authors",function(data) {
        $scope.authors = data;
    });
}
```